# Ansible in Jenkins Ansible plugin, ignores SSH config

Tags: jenkins, ssh, automation, ansible, devops

I'm struggling with an issue regarding SSH control paths in ansible when running with Jenkins using the ansible plugin. The issue is manifested when using long FQDNS for hosts in the inventory.

I've tried the following:

- setting up short host names and control paths in the Jenkins user's SSH config file
- setting SSH args in `/etc/ansible/ansible.cfg` setting, eg:

  ```
  [ssh_connection]
  ssh_args="-F /var/jenkins_home/.ssh/config -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=30m -o ConnectTimeout=60 -o ControlPath=/tmp/ssh-%C"
  control_path="/tmp/ssh-%C"
  ```
- command line option `--ssh-extra-args=` in the Jenkins plugin dialogue

I can't seem to convince Ansible to use a short control path, like the following:

```
" /tmp/ssh-%C"
```

I still get:

> /var/jenkins_home/.ansible/cp/ansible-ssh-bastion-dev.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com-22-jenkins.ivQ6vi6TPB3BrYta\" too long for Unix domain socket

which does not correspond to the option I'm setting everywhere.

Anyone know how to convince the Ansible plugin to stop ignoring the SSH options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works fine for me with `Ansible 2.2.1.0` and `Jenkins ver. 2.32.1`.

```
$ cat /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
[ssh_connection]
control_path = /tmp/ssh-%%C
```

Note double percent sign in `%%C` (otherwise Ansible can't format it).

I'd recommend you to check build node (if you have jenkins slaves, you may change settings on master, but job executes on one of slaves) and run playbook with `-vvvv` additional flags to see what configuration files ansible uses.

Comment: Thank you so much for pointing that out, bit of a n00b issue, I'm blaming temporary blindness

Comment: @barrymac perhaps submit this as a bug report to Ansible to either fix the need for 2 % or better document this.